# SSH host identification while tunneling

Tags: ssh, hostname, tunnel

I have many devices connecting to server thru WebSockets to penetrate NAT and wait incoming connection. At home I have similar situation with NAT so both need outgoing connections.

Basically on device I have python script that make connection betwen

```
ws://myserver/sshtunIn/deviceID
<-->
localhost:22
```

At home I have similar script that expose my

```
localhost:9090 
<-->
ws://myserver/sshtunOut/DeviceID
```

So when I want to connect 1st device I issue:

```
myscryptPrepareStation ws://myserver/sshtunOut/1stDevice
ssh localhost -p9090
```

And to connect 2nd device I issue:

```
myscryptPrepareStation ws://myserver/sshtunOut/2ndDevice
ssh localhost -p9090
```

So the 1st line just expose port 9090 with websocket and 2nd line execute ssh (or scp). As the second line is same on both calls I got warning *fingerprint for the ECDSA changed*
as real device is indeed changed.

I try to add these lines to /etc/host

```
127.0.0.1 1stdevice 
127.0.0.1 2nddevice
```

and then use

```
ssh 1stdevice -p9090 
ssh 2nddevice -p9090
```

and this works. But it isn't practical to change etc/host every time as there are to many devices. So is there some way to use (temporary) different localhost or something else to manage problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I get your problem right, you are connecting to your home server which is changing public facing IP because of your provider resetting the lease like every 24 hours. Thus the warning.

On the client, you can remove the line with the previous IP from `~/.ssh/known_hosts` before connecting.
That way, no warning appears.

Be sure to only do this in the specific case with the IP you know of, otherwise you run into danger by allowing man in the middle attacks on your VPN.

Here is another question with a similiar problem/solution:

https://serverfault.com/questions/559885/temporarily-ignore-my-ssh-known-hosts-file

Keep in mind, this is a very security sensitive thing and not adviced to do if one is not aware of the security implications.

Comment: All my scripts just pass data. The problem is that I do use same command to connect (ssh localhost -p 9090) But I do have changed device with script exposing 9090 on localhost.

Comment: I did try to add 127.0.0.1 DeviceII1, 127.0.0.1 DeviceID2 in /etc/hosts and use ssh with that. It works. Now I need to figure out how to temporarily add hostname possible without sudo.

Comment: @eSlavko can you just connect to the IP `ssh 127.0.0.1 -p 9090` ?

Comment: i do connect with ssh 127.0.0.1 -p9090. But before that I run my script to make connection between port 9090 and websocket

Comment: I edited the question and I hope now is more clear.

Comment: @eSlavko use `127.0.0.1` instead of `myserver`, since from that scope, everything runs on localhost/127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use different ports for your devices.
If each device uses a different port (and it should always be the same for the same device), then the host fingerprint is stored on a port basis.

And all your devices can be access individually.

I used that myself, but the devices uses ssh to create the tunnel. And the port number is assigned by the server on basis of the mac address of the devices (the device sends the mac address on the first request)

```
device -> server: ssh myserver "GetPort <my MAC Addr>"
Response: If MAC is unknown create a new entry with an unused port number
          Send the desired port number

device -> server: ssh myserver -N -R <AssingedPortNumber>:localhost:22

home->device: ssh -o ProxyJump=myServer user@localhost -p devicePortNumber
```